# HashSet of integers

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, abstract-class, hashset

```
public class MyClass<Integer> extends AnotherOne<Integer> {
    public MyClass(HashSet<Integer> ar) {    
        super(ar);
    } 
}
```

`AnotherOne` is an abstract(generic) class which has a constructor which gets `HashSet<T>` as a parameter. Then it has another method which uses the `T` type for its parameters.

Everything is ok but I have to use `Integer` as a parameter to override that method and using `Integer` instead of `int` seems weird. Is there a way to use the primitive int?

Comment: was there any question about it?

Comment: @Leo please put it in an answer if it's worth telling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, generics cannot have a primitive type as the generic type parameter; it must be a reference type, such as `Integer`.

Additionally, you are declaring a generic type parameter `Integer` that is now hiding the actual `java.lang.Integer` class.  If `MyClass` wasn't itself meant to be generic, then remove it from the class:

```
public class MyClass extends AnotherOne<Integer>
```

If it was, use a single capital letter for the generic type parameter:

```
public class MyClass<T> extends AnotherOne<T>
```

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot use primitive int for a HashSet.

This is valid for all other generic collection classes too.

Comment: ok but is it safe to use Integer? It looks very weird to have a method which gets arguments public void method(Integer i,Integer k)

Comment: It is safe. And it doesn't look weird to me. Alternatively, you can pass int to your method but convert to Integer and add Integer to your collection. Depends on your exact use case and your preferences.